# Struts class variable ( coming through request ) initialize to null in the finally block of action

Tags: class, variables, null, initialization, struts

In struts 2 action I am getting parameter though request. So I defined a variables in the action. Now the architect is insisting to initialize this variable to null in the finally block of execute method of action. I am against it. Because, I am not initializing these class variables, but framework initializing these variables. But architect insisting that the program will consume more memory if we will not free java variables.

Please give me solid reason why should not initialize: variable of action class  to null in the finally block of execute method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of having fields in Struts actions is to be able to access them in the view, once the `execute()` method has done its job. Setting the field to null will simply prevent the view to access the field value, which is, most of the time, precisely not what you want.

Furthermore, even if the field is not used by the view, Java has this marvellous thing called the garbage collector, which will happily garbage-collect the action and its referenced objects if they're not reachable anymore. Since actions are very short-lived objects (they stay alive for the duration of a request, i.e. a few milliseconds), the garbage-collector will be able to collect them very fast, and they won't consume memory for long. Setting them to null is completely unnecessary.